# CMake set cache is taking "CACHE" as a variable

Tags: cmake

I am trying to override the default value of MY_VAR from command line, but I get an unexpected result:

Excerpt from my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set( MY_VAR MY_VAR_DEF_VALUE CACHE INTERNAL "This is my_var" [FORCE] )
message( "MY_VAR = ${MY_VAR}" )
```

cmake command:

```
cmake -DMY_VAR:INTERNAL=MY_VAR_USER_VALUE ..
```

Output:

```
MY_VAR = MY_VAR_DEF_VALUE;CACHE;INTERNAL;This is my_var;[FORCE]
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
MY_VAR = MY_VAR_USER_VALUE
```

The weird part is that MY_VAR gets updated properly in CMakeCache.txt, see excerpt:

```
//No help, variable specified on the command line.

MY_VAR:INTERNAL=MY_VAR_USER_VALUE
```

NOTE: I am doing an out of source build

UPDATE (11/15/15):

I removed the square brackets around FORCE, the output is:

> MY_VAR = MY_VAR_DEF_VALUE

I removed FORCE, the output is:

> MY_VAR = MY_VAR_DEF_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

It works in such way:

```
cd path/to/build/dir && cmake -DVAR=VALUE path/to/src
```

First of all cmake run script from `path/to/src/CMakeLists.txt`(step 1)
after that it sets `VAR` to proper value (step 2).
In CMakeLitst.txt you have:

```
set(VAR DEF_VALUE FORCE)
message(STATUS "VAR: ${VAR}")
```

`FORCE` tell cmake rewrite cache, so at step 1 you have default value,
after that cmake print its value and of course it is `DEF_VALUE`,
after that it sets CACHE with `-D` command.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[FORCE]` option from your set command and replace the `INTERNAL` option with one of the keywords which indicates the type of your variable (`BOOL`, `STRING`, etc.). The `FORCE` option would cause your `CMakeLists.txt` to override whatever you specify on the command line. Specifying `INTERNAL` implies `FORCE` (see [the CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html)).

Part of the odd behaviour you are seeing is likely because you have included square brackets around `FORCE`. The square brackets should not be there if you *did* want to use `FORCE` (the square brackets in the CMake documentation are there just to indicate that it is an optional parameter).

Comment: Craig, <type> & <docstring> are mandatory fields for CACHE mode, if I remove INTERNAL, I get the following error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (set):
  set given invalid arguments for CACHE mode.

Comment: My answer may not have been clear. I re-worded it to make it clear that you need to _change_ INTERNAL to one of the specified types, not remove it completely.

Comment: None of the other 4 types meet my requirement, I am actually using MY_VAR as a folder name within a predefined path. i.e. /path/to/${MY_VAR}/folder. I want the value to persist over consecutive cmake calls, so I think INTERNAL would have been the ideal choice if it worked.

Comment: INTERNAL is basically equivalent to STRING as far as I can tell. STRING essentially means it gets no special treatment in the CMake GUI, with a simple line edit provided to modify its value.